# If a function $f$ satisfies $f(2x+3)=x^2$, how to find $f(0)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> If a function satisfies $f(2x+3)=x^2$, what is $f(0)$?

Explain how you figured it out, please.

Comment: Explain what you tried, please.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

Put $2x+3=0$ in $f(2x+3)=x^2$

More generally, we can find $f(y)$  as follows:

let $2x+3=y\implies f(y)=\left(\frac{y-3}2\right)^2$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $2x + 3 = 0 \iff x = \frac{-3}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

You might use Maple to make @lab's approach machinery:

```
 [> h := x-> x^2:
    g := x-> 2*x+3:
      solve(g(x) = t, x):
       subs(x = %, h(x)):
    simplify(%);

                                     (1/4)*(t-3)^2
```

Comment: Nice work, @Babak!

Answer (score 2):

You have $$f[g(x)]=x^2$$
To find $f[0]$, just solve the equation $g(x)=0$.

In this case $g(x)=2x+3=0\iff x=-3/2.$ 
Thus $f[g(-3/2)]=f[0]=(-3/2)^2=9/4.$ since $f[g(x)]=x^2$.

Comment: Actually $2x+3=0 \Rightarrow x=-1.5$. Please fix it (for some reason I couldn't suggest an edit...)

Comment: @Galc127 ${}{{{{}}}}-1.5=-3/2$.

Comment: At first, you have written $2x+3=0 \Rightarrow x=-2/3$.

Comment: @Galc127 Yes, my error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you a slightly different approach (which is based on function composition as the other answers, though):

Define $\square = 2x + 3$, so $x = \frac{\square - 3}{2}$, then your function becomes:

$$f(\square) = x^2 = \left(\frac{\square - 3}{2}\right)^2,$$

so $f(0) = 9/4$.

Cheers!